# How to load image to object and set default if error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, javascript-objects

I have container where I should load the image. The image has actual image that is unique for each `id`. If image doesn't exist for that id then it should load default image. Here is example of what I have:

```
function addImage() {
    var image = new Image();
    image.addEventListener('load', function () {
        this.src = 'images/'+id+'_image01.jpg';
    });
    image.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
        // Image not found, show the default
        image.src = 'images/default.jpg';
    });
    image.width = 233;
    console.log(image);
 }
```

The output of the function above in the console looks like this:

```
<img width="233">
```

The only attribute that is appended to image object is `width`. I'm wondering why source is not appended. It should look like this:

```
<img width="233" src="images/89_image01.jpg"> //Image exist
```

or this if image does not exist:

```
<img width="233" src="images/default.jpg"> //Image does not exist
```

I'm not sure why my function only attached width. If anyone can detect the problem please let me know.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Any other approach to prevent this?

Comment: Also, you are setting the `src` inside the handler. The handler doesn't run until it gets an image — it won't get an image until it has a src.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I'm not sure that I understand your question.

Comment: See answer below for code example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the src attribute to the image object after outside the onload event handler so it actually call that event handler or call the onerror event handler.

```
function addImage(id) {
var image = new Image();
image.addEventListener('error', function onError (e) {
    // Image not found, show the default
    image.removeEventListener(error, onError);
    image.src = 'images/default.jpg';
});
image.width = 233;
image.src = 'images/'+id+'_image01.jpg';
console.log(image);
```

}

Also, don't forget to remove the onError event handler once the default image has loaded, this will save a few headaches if you default image is not found.